# How can I change the Multimedia Backend in Qt 5.7?

Tags: qt

Hello I developed an application on linux that is a music player with an spectrum analyzer.

Now I want to compile it for windows.

However, it turns out that DirectShow does not support audio probe as stated here:
https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.7_Multimedia_Backends

But apparently Media Foundation does. How can I use this backend instead of DirectShow?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here -- neither backend is supported in Linux. Is this a question about porting to Windows?

Comment: I`m sorry. Yes. I want to compile the application in windows. I´ve edited my question

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end? Thanks

Comment: @SamG101. Sorry, man. This was years ago. And no. I never did find a solution.